# Can't download sdk -- 404 error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I install the Android Studio, when I was going to downloading the sdk, something happened like following:

```
enter code herePreparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 400
Downloading Samples for SDK API 19, revision 6
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 400
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 400
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager from Android Studio and download them again.

The HTTP Status 400 is

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.